# SQLAlchemy foreign key filtering, using a different field than the foreign key field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a similar setup to a customer list / orders 'classic' model. In my case it's SEC data, where one model maps tickers to CIK (which is the SEC's id # for reporting entities). The CIK and ticker are unique for each company. Another table holds information regarding reports; a company can have multiple reports (quartely earnings, annual..). I'm using CIK as the foreign key to tie tickers and reports.

The goal is to filter by *ticker* and get all the reports associated with a company. The following statment 'works' (as is, no error is returned), but retrieves reports from all the companies, not just the required one (e.g., yahoo's reports):

```
for instance in session.query(SEC_RSS_Model).filter(CIK_Model.ticker == 'YHOO'):
    print instance.edgarlink
```

The above statement prints the entire content of SEC_RSS (The table associated with **SEC_RSS_Model**), namely, no filtering is taking place at all.

My SQLAlchemy models:

```
class CIK_Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CIK_Table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    CIK = Column(String(10), unique=True)
    ticker = Column(String(8))
    RSS = relationship("SEC_RSS_Model", backref="CIK_Table")

def __init__(self, CIK, ticker):
    self.CIK = CIK
    self.ticker = ticker

def __repr__(self):
    return "<CIK_Table('%s','%s')>" % (self.CIK, self.ticker)
```

and

```
class SEC_RSS_Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'SEC_RSS'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    CIK = Column(String(10),ForeignKey ( "CIK_Table.CIK" ))
    edgarlink = Column(String(128), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, CIK, edgarlink):
        self.CIK = CIK
        self.edgarlink = edgarlink

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<SEC_RSS('%s','%s')>" % (self.CIK, self.edgarlink)
```

What am I defining wrong here? Is this model many-to-one or one-to-many? Is the relationship setup properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join on the relationship for the query to work:

```
session.query(SEC_RSS_Model).join(SEC_RSSL_Model.CIK_Table).filter(CIK_Model.ticker == 'YHOO')
```